# automatic build trigger from jenkins, when changes are done to particular branch in gitlab

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

i have a build script in a separate  'xyz branch' in gitlab, this script is pointing to 'release branch' sources to build,

i have configured freestyle job in jenkins so that it will clone the build script from 'xyz branch'.

now i want a automatic build trigger from jenkins when changes are done in 'release branch'.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can configure gitlab jenkins plugin to accomplish this.

Refer:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#job-trigger-configuration

Comment: hi, i tried those steps, but it is not working.  the 'script branch'  holds the build script, which i configured in jenkins, and daily i am updating changes in 'release branch'. build should be triggered automatically when changes are done to 'release branch'